# $a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$; prove $a_n+1=2^n(a_0+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

If the sequence $a_n$ satisfies $a_n = 2a_{n-1}+1$ for all $n \geq 1$, show that for every $n \geq 0$, we have $a_n+1 = 2^n(a_0+1)$.

I thought of letting $a_n = c^n$ and $a^{n-1} = c^{n-1}$ then solving that way, but the extra $1$ makes it difficult.

Comment: You can get your method to work by expanding your guess to include a few more constants, $a_n=Ac^n+B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $$a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$$
$$a_n+1=2a_{n-1}+2=2(a_{n-1}+1)$$
$$a_n+1=2(a_{n-1}+1)=2^2(a_{n-2}+1)$$ and so on.

Can you prove now?

Comment: Yes, would an informal argument such as "the pattern continues down to $a_0$" prove it or would using a characteristic equation be better?

Comment: Considering your question, this kind of informal argument looks purely logical. Your question does not demand a characteristic equation.